# .NET 4.5/WPF - Binding to the property of a static property

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, binding, static

So I am trying to bind a TextBlock to the Count property of a ObserverableCollection with the following XAML

```
<TextBlock x:Name="inactiveCount">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <Binding Path="(sockets:Manager.inactiveCollection.Count)" Mode="OneWay" StringFormat="Inactive: {0}" />
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

But I receive a exception when running the program:

```
Type reference cannot find type named '{clr-namespace:MyProgram.Net.Sockets;assembly=MyProgram}Manager.inactiveCollection'.
```

Binding to other properties in the Manager class work fine, and inactiveCollection certainly does exist as a static property. What exactly am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

So per fmunkert's suggestions below i've changed it to

```
<TextBlock x:Name="inactiveCount">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <Binding Path="Count" Source="(sockets:Manager.inactiveCollection)" Mode="OneWay" StringFormat="Inactive: {0}" />
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

and it kind of works. It displays the wrong number for the count, 52 when there are 233 objects in the collection which is initialized in Manager's static constructor. And it never updates as objects are removed from the collection

**Edit 2**

```
namespace MyProgram.Net.Sockets
{
//technically this is ProxyClientManager but I renamed it here to make the code smaller
    class Manager
    {
        public static ObservableCollection<ProxyClient> inactiveCollection { get; set; }

        static Manager()
        {
            inactiveCollection = new ObservableCollection<ProxyClient>();
            //do stuff to populate inactiveCollection with 233 objects
            //do other stuff like start threads to add/remove objects from the collection
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should post the code with the declaration of `Manager.inactiveCollection` and the code that shows how you add/remove items.

Comment: done. the actuall population of it is rather involved with some SQL queries, how it is populated isnt exactly important, at the end of the static constructor it contains 233 objects.

Comment: You need to use `x:Static` in Source as suggested by fmunkert in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So fmunkert was partially right, I needed to specify a source, but I also needed to specify a StaticResource for the class in Window.Resources. The following XAML worked for me:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <sockets:Manager x:Key="Manager"/>
</Window.Resources>
<TextBlock x:Name="inactiveCount" Text="{Binding Path='inactiveCollection.Count', Source='{StaticResource Manager}', StringFormat='Inactive: {0}'}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `{x:Static}` for the binding source, e.g. like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Count, Source={x:Static sockets:Manager.inactiveCollection}, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat='Inactive: {0}'}"/>
```

Comment: Just wondering but would you happen to know why it displays an incorrect value for the binding? For instance it says "Inactive: 52" when there are 233 objects in the collection? Also it doesnt seem to update at all when objects are added/removed from the collection?

Comment: Also it tells me when I use your Text value, that inactiveCollection cannot be found in ProxyClientManager. But it will find it I use the XAML with the changes mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: What relationship does the `ProxyClientManager` class have with the `Manager.inactiveCollection` property? Is the data type of `Manager.inactiveCollection` really `ObservableCollection<T>`?

Comment: `ProxyClientManager` is `Manager`, I just renamed it here to make the code here smaller. I forgot to change that in my comment. Yes `inactiveCollection` is really a `ObservableCollection<T>`. It is initialized and populated in the class's static constructor. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It is always the same `ObservableCollection`. Objects are added/removed to/from it, it is never replaced with another collection.

Comment: Do I need to subclass `ObservableCollection`, and raise `PropertyChanged` events when objects are added to/removed from it to have the `Count` binding updated?

Comment: No, `ObservableCollection<T>` already implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Ok, I wasnt sure if `Count` was one of the properties which it raises events for.